# Suspicious connections coming from Firefox (possible malware)

Tags: firefox, security, malware

I was playing around with Wireshark when I noticed something very suspicious: every time I open Firefox (official build from Ubuntu repos), it immediately connects to a server with an apparently random name like `d2ddoduugvun08.cloudfront.net` and sends some encrypted data.

I couldn't find anything specific on this domain, but it pops up on some malware sites.

At first I thought it was some Firefox telemetry server but it is disabled and the server is not a Mozilla server.

I deleted my `~/.mozilla` folder, in case my profile was the problem, but the connection was still there every time.

At this point I thought my installation of Firefox was compromised, so I purged it and redownloaded it from the repos. The connection was still there.

I moved to another machine with Windows, and it doesn't make this connection; when I booted into an Ubuntu live USB, it does.

I decided to build Firefox from source and it does not make this connection.

I tried to use `mitmproxy` to intercept it but it ignores my system proxy settings.

So my question is: is this a legit thing added by Canonical? Is the Firefox package on Ubuntu compromised by some malware?

Thanks

Comment: cloudfront.net is a cloud computing service, they're not likely to be involved directly in malware, any more than the bank that a mobster has his checking account in is involved in crime.

Comment: Related, please see this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363512/chrome-dns-requests-with-random-dns-names-malware/363513

Answer (score 20):

It [appears](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1076594) to be [firefox heartbeat telemetry](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Shield/Heartbeat). It could be disabled in `about:config` settings (that particular one can probably be disabled with `app.normandy.enabled=false` in `about:config`)

If you do not like firefox phoning home (and elsewhere), there are also a few other settings [you may want to change](http://www.trek.eu.org/text/firefox-tuning.html)

Comment: Is that particular CloudFront distribution known to be associated with telemetry?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be from canonical as a whois check d2ddoduugvun08.cloudfront.net reveals the following:

```
Registrant Name: Legal Department
Registrant Organization: Amazon.com, Inc.
Registrant Street: PO BOX 81226
Registrant City: Seattle
Registrant State/Province: WA
Registrant Postal Code: 98108-1226
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone: +1.2062664064
Registrant Phone Ext: 
Registrant Fax: +1.2062667010
Registrant Fax Ext: 
Registrant Email: email@amazon.com
Registry Admin ID: 
Admin Name: Legal Department
Admin Organization: Amazon.com, Inc.
```

So it is not malware. This site is helpful https://www.whois.com/whois/

Comment: That's what I found too, but how do I disable it? Telemetry is disabled in the system settings. How do I know what is being sent?

Comment: "but how do I disable it? Telemetry is disabled in the system settings. How do I know what is being sent?" was not part of the original question.

Comment: How this helps to tell that this is not a malware? Anyone can rent servers from amazon.

Comment: Some would consider telemetry to be malware...

Comment: And amazon will just allow malware to be hosted on their servers @jiv

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen: they rent to anyone, with encrypted traffic and software it might take time to recognize what it is.